# float comparison problem objective c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, comparison, floating-point

strange behavior:

(xcode 4 breakpoint screenshot)
[image: http://img3.picload.org/image/lawgcd/untitled.png]

why does this comparison yield true? I really dont get it..

Comment: Read this paper by Goldberg before doing any more programming involving floating point arithmetic: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Are you sure you're running the debugger on a "Debug" build? If you're running it on an optimised build with debugging symbols stripped, your debugger will have a very hard time matching breakpoints to lines in your source code.

Answer (score 6):

The code seems to be working correctly,
are you sure the comparison validates true?

**Quick snippet:**

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    float value = (arc4random()%100)/(float)100.0f;
    NSLog(@"%f",value);
    if(value < 0.01f) {
        NSLog(@"YES");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"NO");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
0.520000
NO
0.520000
NO
0.100000
NO
0.000000
YES
0.390000
NO
0.690000
NO
0.770000
NO
0.930000
NO
0.320000
NO
0.230000
NO
```

**EDIT - Response to comment:**

In my case, the breakpoints are working correctly:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking time to look into this! The strange thing is that the test seems to yield true. At least when i set a breakpoint on the return, the debugger hits it.

Comment: On my Mac everything is working properly, checkout the screenshot.

Comment: Hi Anne, thanks again for taking time to reproduce this! I also did some tests meanwhile and it seems, the comparison actually does not yield true in my case. However, if i am in debug mode and set a breakpoint on the return in my if-body, the breakpoint is hit everytime just before the function is left. I am currently not sure why this happens in xcode/obj-c but the results are correct. Thanks again for your help and your time!